# separador decimal y de miles segun configuración regional del sistema operativo

Tags: c#, decimal

En un método encargado de convertir un Datatable en un listado de objetos, al covertir algunos de los campos a decimales:

```
Capacidad = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Capacidad"]),2),
Unidad = Convert.ToString(dr["Tipo Unidad"]),
NumeroEnvases = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Numero Envases"]),2),
VolumenTotal = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Volumen Total"]),2),
```

me da el error:

> System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'

Esto es por qué en la configuración regional del sistema tengo configurado la separación de miles con una "," y la de la de los decimales con un "."
Si establezco la configuración a la inversa, funciona sin problemas.
Mi pregunta és:
¿Cómo puedo solventar esto teniendo en cuenta de que ambas configuraciones pueden ser las establecidas en el sistema?

Muchas gracias, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes usar es un `Replace` para cambiar el "." o "," y así usar a tu conveniencia el tema de convertir el valor decimal con una "," o un ".". Algo como:

```
VolumenTotal = decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Volumen Total"].ToString().Replace(".", ",")), 2),
```